# Split json array into smaller in a specific format in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a huge json array file downloaded which needs to be split into smaller files but I need the smaller files in the below format (newline for each new object in array): (original json is also in the same format)

```
[
{"a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1"},
{"a":"a2","b":"b2","c":"c2"},
{"a":"a3","b":"b3","c":"c3"}
]
```

I used json.dump but it is just printing the smaller array in a single line and using the indent option is also not giving me the output in the above format

Comment: are there no quotation marks on purpose? I'm not sure that is valid json...

Comment: mind shedding light on why it must be in a specific format instead of just readable json?

Comment: @ Tadhg McDonald-Jensen : missed the quotations, added them now

Comment: Need more information. What does the original json look like?

Comment: @ AndrewSmiley original json is also in the same format

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't know what your original json looks like, you would basically want something like this

```
lines = []
for something in original_json:
    line={something['a']:something['aa']} #whatever you need to do to get your  values
    lines.append(line) 
    #alternatively you can simplify this by doing lines.append({something['a']:something['aa'], etc}
with open('myfile.json', 'a+') as f1:
    f1.write("[\n")
    for line in lines:
         f1.write("%s,\n"%(line))
    f1.write("]")
```

Comment: does `dumps` format differently than `dump`? i think the op wanted the specific line break an spacing format of the example output.

Comment: dumps does behave differently, but I will update my answer to reflect the spacing

Comment: See above. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to get that kind of formatting.

Comment: you need to be cautious of the brackets and number of commas, methinks.

Comment: Yeah you would do better to do a for loop vs a for each loop to not add the additional comma on the last dict item. This is quick and dirty, didn't want to hand him the code, but rather point him in the right directino.